# using jwysiwyg and validation issues

Tags: jquery

I'd like to focus the cursor in the jwysiwyg iframe when the user forgets to enter a value but I'm not sure how to do this. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no mechanism for moving the mouse via javascript.

To focus in iframe use this script (if you use jquery)

```
$(".wysiwyg").find("iframe").focus();
```

To access the content of iframe you have to use the above script :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wysiwyg").find("iframe").load(function(){
       var test =  $(".wysiwyg").find("iframe").contents().find('body').html();
       //do job with the content.
       //Remember that jwysiwyg will produse some code even if it seems there is 
       //nothing.(couse the wysiwyg is base on browser behavor
    });
});
```